# Trying to join three tables together and getting a syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I am trying to write a postgres query that will join three tables together. I believe I have everything correct but when I run the query I get back a syntax error:

```
select
cwd_user.id,
cwd_user.user_name username,
cwd_user.email_address emailaddress,
cwd_user.active active
cwd_user.created_date created
cwd_membership.child_id 
cwd_membership.parent_name groupname
licenserolesgroup.id
licenserolesgroup.license_role_name application
from
cwd_user
inner join cwd_membership on cwd_membership.child_id = cwd_user.id
inner join licenserolesgroup on cwd_membership.child_id =         licenserolesgroup.id;
```

The query should be able to output:

- userID
- userName
- emailAddress
- active
- createdDate
- childID (used to match against the group table)
- groupName
- licenseID
- application

Any help on this would be appreciated. I have not done a lot with joins. Trial by fire I guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a bunch of trailing commas. Try instead:

```
select
cwd_user.id,
cwd_user.user_name username,
cwd_user.email_address emailaddress,
cwd_user.active active,
cwd_user.created_date created,
cwd_membership.child_id,
cwd_membership.parent_name groupname,
licenserolesgroup.id,
licenserolesgroup.license_role_name application
from
cwd_user
inner join cwd_membership on cwd_membership.child_id = cwd_user.id
inner join licenserolesgroup on cwd_membership.child_id = licenserolesgroup.id;
```

Comment: LOL Wow   I even thought when I was typing it up, I need to make sure I put commas after each line.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any error message in posts. I assume that's because of missing ',' (comma) character at end of each field?

```
select
cwd_user.id,
cwd_user.user_name username,
cwd_user.email_address emailaddress,
cwd_user.active active,
cwd_user.created_date created,
cwd_membership.child_id, 
cwd_membership.parent_name groupname,
licenserolesgroup.id,
licenserolesgroup.license_role_name application
from
cwd_user
inner join cwd_membership on cwd_membership.child_id = cwd_user.id
inner join licenserolesgroup on cwd_membership.child_id = licenserolesgroup.id;
```